# Rails 5 - Can't Render Associons with as_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

Explanation:
I have 2 models, User and Interests, associated by a has_and_belongs_to_many. When a User is created I need to create all the interests and make the correct associations. Its an API, so I use as_json to render the response, but for some reason when I delete previous associations (self.interests.delete_all) and create new ones inside associate_interests method they don't render to the response. If I remove the "self.interests.delete_all", it renders all the associated interests.
I wasn't able to find a post related to this problem.
Thank You.

Migration

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
    def change
        create_table :users do |t|
            t.string :avatar
            t.string :description
            t.string :email
            t.string :institution
            t.string :name
            t.string :orcid
            t.string :password_digest
            t.string :research_area
            t.string :username
            t.timestamps
        end

        create_table :interests do |t|
            t.string :hashtag, unique: true
            t.timestamps
        end

        create_table :interests_users, id: false do |t|
            t.belongs_to :user, index: true
            t.belongs_to :interest, index: true
        end

        add_index :interests_users, [:user_id, :interest_id], unique: true
    end
end
```

UserController create method

```
def create
    params = user_params
    @user = User.new(params.except(:interests))

    if @user.save
      @user.associate_interests(params[:interests]) if params.key?(:interests)
      render @user.info, status: :created
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :bad_request
end
```

User Model

```
require "file_size_validator"

class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password
    has_and_belongs_to_many :interests
    validates_presence_of :username, :name, :orcid, :research_area, :institution
    validates_uniqueness_of :username, :email, :orcid
    validates :avatar, file_size: { maximum: 2.megabytes }

    mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

    def info
        as_json(
            except: [:password_digest, :avatar],
            include: [:interests, {
                avatar: {
                    only: :url
                }
            }])
    end

    def associate_interests(s_interests)
        # Have all interest models and create if they dont exist
        self.interests.delete_all

        ints = []
        s_interests.each do |hashtag|
            i = Interest.new(hashtag: hashtag)
            if i.save
                ints.push(i)
            else
                ints.push(Interest.find_by(hashtag: hashtag))
            end
        end

        # Create association between user and interests
        ints.each do |i|
            i.users.push(self)
        end
    end
end
```

Response with self.interests.delete_all

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "example",
    "username": "example",
    "email": "example@gmail.com",
    "institution": "UCcccccaaaaaaaafdasfadsfadsfadsafaa",
    "orcid": "123213213213",
    "research_area": "bbb",
    "description": "helloo its me",
    "created_at": "2018-10-14T22:56:26.833Z",
    "interests": []
}
```

Response without self.interests.delete_all

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "example",
    "username": "example",
    "email": "example@gmail.com",
    "institution": "UCcccccaaaaaaaafdasfadsfadsfadsafaa",
    "orcid": "123213213213",
    "research_area": "bbb",
    "description": "helloo its me",
    "created_at": "2018-10-14T23:25:47.976Z",
    "interests": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "hashtag": "aaaa",
            "created_at": "2018-10-14T23:25:47.999Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "hashtag": "bbbb",
            "created_at": "2018-10-14T23:25:48.004Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the user to the reverse `users` association of the interest, but the user itself remains unaware of the fact since the collection has already been loaded once.

You can either change the code from `i.users.push(self)` to `interests << i` or add a `interests.reload` at the end of the method to load the changes from the database.

Comment: Thank You so much, I had no idea what was happening. One question, When is the collection loaded for the first time?

Comment: When you try to access any of the records by calling `.first`, `.each` etc..It's also interesting to note that the implementation of some of the methods works differently depending on whether the collection has already been loaded: for example `.any?` and `.count` will run a `COUNT` SQL query if the collection hasn't been loaded already and check against the in-memory data if it has.